# how to delete values of cells based on the value of another cell in python?

Tags: python

I am a *complete* newbie to data analysis and have a question regarding a survey analysis with Python. The study (it’s about cultivated meat) was conducted on google forms.

Here is my problem:
There is a question about weekly meat consumption (question 6) and then a question about the willingness to reduce one’s meat consumption (question 9).
Now I would like to delete a person’s answer in the column of question 9, if that person answered ‚never‘ in question 6. (Because you can’t reduce your consumption of meat, when you don’t eat any meat, right?).

How do I do this? I don't even know how to approach this problem :(

Here's a picture to illustrate what I mean:
[picture of dataframe including mentioned cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yJg1.jpg)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Please include your data in a copy-pastable text format instead of an image.

Comment: @Tobi208 thank you for your feedback! How do I do that tho?

Comment: Copy the first few lines of your csv file and paste them in the question. Wrap them in tripple backticks ` to format them. It makes debugging code with dataframes much more comfortable and increases your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: @Tobi208 thank you so much, I will include that next time I ask a question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitue 'col9' and 'col6' with the real names of your columns.
Instead of np.nan you can use anything else that signifies a 'dead' cell for you.

This assigns every cell in col9 either its current value if the corresponding cell in col6 is not 'nie' or a 'dead' value.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def erase_if_never(x):
    if x[0] == 'nie':
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[1]


df['col9'] = df[['col6', 'col9']].apply(erase_if_never, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace it with a nan value.

```
def delete_cell(x):
     if x == 'never':
          return np.nan
     else:
          return x

df['col9'] = df['col6'].apply(lambda x: delete_cell(x))
```

Comment: That will set every value in 'col9' to nan.

Comment: Yes made the change, thanks

Comment: That would transfer values != 'never' from col6 to col9